# Add quotes only around strings, not numbers or lists

Tags: json, jq

My input JSON is of the format:

```
{
  "a": "apple",
  "b": "banana",
  "c": 5,
  "d": ["this", "is", "an", "array"],
  "e": false
}
```

What I want is:

```
a="apple"
b="banana"
c=5
d=["this", "is", "an", "array"]
e=false
```

Note that only strings in the input JSON have quotes in the output.

By using `jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key)=\"\(.value)\""'` I could generate an output like

```
a="apple"
b="banana"
c="5"
d="["this", "is", "an", "array"]"
e="false"
```

So my question is:

1. Is using jq the right way to approach this problem? Or should I use regex?
2. If jq is the correct direction, how do I fix what I've come up with?

Comment: The input is not JSON. Object keys must be quoted strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test whether .value is a string or not using `type` ([manual entry](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions)).

```
jq -r 'to_entries[]
      | "\(.key) = \( .value 
                      | if type == "string"
                        then "\"\(.)\""
                        else . 
                        end
                    )"'
```